# Dashed lines added in Word 2010 display on screen but do not print

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am trying to make rules lines for my literacy student. The lines (solid, dashed, solid) look fine on the screen, but when I print the page, only the solid lines are printed. I am using Word 2010. I had a similar situation with text boxes, also displayed fine but didn't print.  Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to enhance the print density on your printer that is, make the lines darker? Also, is there enough ink in your printer as low ink would cause print jobs to be incomplete?